# using java lock or catch database exception

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, race-condition

Every time when new data comes in, I will check the database, if there is a record correlated to the new data, I will get it and update the record based on the new data and the old record; if no record exists, I will create a new record to for the new data;

**Issue:** when there are several threads do the same thing it will naturally form a `read -> check -> update` pattern, resulting in a [*race condition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

---

I've tried the following solutions but both of them seems not quite good.

1. Add unique constraint to db for `aFieldOrSeveralFields`, try to catch `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` and then retry the `read -> check -> update` process;

   - I can catch `Exception` but it looks **dangerous** to me;
   - or I can check it by `e instanceof SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` and let other exceptions bubble up but it looks **ugly**;
2. Using `synchronised` to the whole `read -> check -> update` but it seems quite **ineffective** since there are obvious I/O operations.

---

#### Updated 2019-03-11

In the end, to balance the *ugly processing* and *effectiveness*, I split up the task into smaller ones using `synchronised` to ensure the data consistence and till now no obvious performance issues rise.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing the right thing, but what is I don't understand is why an exception is being thrown in here   ?  (maybe you can clarify it).

As I see it the right flow goes like this:

```
record <- readFromDB(uniqueFields)
if record does not exist:
    record <- createRecord()
updateFields(record) //here you should update the non-unique fields
saveToDB(record)     //it shouldn't throw an exception since the unique fields didn't change
```

---

Another possible solution is by using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE/IGNORE based on your use case, read more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html),

Comment: Sorry but I think you misunderstood my question. Would you please kindly check the requirements in the question? Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry its not clear enough, can you please explain ?

Comment: Soooorry for my bad abstraction, I will update it and let you know once I update it....sorry, have a nice day!

Comment: Sorry for such delay, I just updated my question. I hope it now can better express my intents.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it depends on your service scenario. If you need a callback immediately, there are three ways.

> First one,  pessimistic lock. This one is used in the money related scenario like account balance.

```
select xx from xxx.. for update
//check
//update
```

> Second one, optimistic lock. If you are not satisfied with the efficiency for the first one. It maybe a choice for you. At the mean time, you got to afford the complicated plan if race condition shows up. Simply throwing an exception is not an enterprise plan.

```
select version, xxx,... from ... //version column is for optimistic lock
//check
update .... set ... where version = (the version you get above)
```

> Or, maybe you can try the event driven model with message queue